# Is it possible to store constructed images for display later using Java Swing?

Tags: java, image, swing, buffer, layer

I am a C/C++ programmer trying my hand at Java for the first time. I'm currently working on a program that reads in a bunch of data and builds a map. I want to give the user the option to toggle various features of the map using check boxes.

In the Win32 API, I was able to accomplish this by pre-building the features on transparent bitmaps and then BitBlt()ing them over top one another. Does Java Swing support something similar? I imagine I'm not the only person who has ever wanted to do this. Building the features is relatively slow, so I only want to generate the layers once and then block copy them to the JPanel I'm using as a display.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store images in Swing using the `BufferedImage` class, and then use that to later draw the final image.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html

The final image can later be painted on to the JPanel (probably by overriding the JPanel's `paintComponent` method) by using the alpha values of the images.

Comment: Perfect! That's just the sort of functionality I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could dynamically create BufferedImage objects, with alpha channels, then only paint this on a frame if the checkbox is checked.